# I have an argument issue and I can't figure out why?

Tags: python, class, pygame

I am working with some classes to try to write a small game. I created a method to move an object on the screen and added key binds.

I expect the square to move however it just gives out an error. Could you please explain why it gives me this error?

Code:

```
class shape():
    def __init__(self, place, colour, x, y):
        self.place = place
        self.colour = colour
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


#class for a rectangle
class rectangle(shape):
    def __init__(self, place, colour, x, y, length, width):
        super().__init__(place, colour, x, y)
        self.length = length
        self.width = width
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, colour, pygame.Rect(x, y, length, width))

    def move_up():
        self.y = self.y + 3

    def move_down():
        self.y = self.y - 3

    def move_right():
        self.x = self.x + 3

    def move_left():
        self.x = left.x - 3



#creating a rectangle
Rectangle = rectangle(screen, yellow, x, y, 60, 60)


#main loop
while not done:

        #checking for game events
        for event in pygame.event.get():


                #quitting gamw when window is closed
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        done = True

        #detecting key presses
        key_press = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key_press[pygame.K_UP]: Rectangle.move_up()
        if key_press[pygame.K_DOWN]:Rectangle.move_down()
        if key_press[pygame.K_LEFT]:Rectangle.move_left()
        if key_press[pygame.K_RIGHT]:Rectangle.move_right()





        pygame.display.flip()
```

I receive this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Pygame.py", line 73, in <module>
    if key_press[pygame.K_RIGHT]:Rectangle.move_right()
TypeError: move_right() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

and I am not sure why.

Comment: You need to pass `self` as an argument to `move_right()`, so `move_right(self)`

Comment: Just to note, usually classes would start with a capital letter: `CamelCase`, and names referring to objects would be lower case with words separated by underscores: `snake_case`. So, `Rectangle` and `rectangle` should be swapped. Also `shape` should be `Shape`. See [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all this methods

```
def move_up():

def move_down():

def move_right():

def move_left():
```

are actually methods of the class **rectangle**, so all them need the "self" parameter, you have to edit them to:

```
def move_up(self):
    self.y = self.y + 3

def move_down(self):
    self.y = self.y - 3

def move_right(self):
    self.x = self.x + 3

def move_left(self):
    self.x = left.x - 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Rectangle is a class and move_right is a method of that class. Therefore you must pass it self as argument.